# Using Self Calling Anonymous Functions and $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just recently learned about self calling anonymous functions.  Some snippets of code that I came across used the self calling function along with the $(document).ready.  It seems redundant, or pointless, to use both.

Is there a case where you'd use

```
(function(){
   $(document).ready();
})();
```

vs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   (function(){})();
});
```

I figure that you'd either want the script to be executed right away or after the DOM loaded.  I can't see why you'd use both together.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - they're not equivalent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's definitely a use case for the first example.  If you have other JS libraries/scripts loaded on the same page, there's no guarantee that they aren't overwriting the `$` variable.  (This is very common when you have Prototype and jQuery on the same page).

So if Prototype is using `$`, you would need to use `jQuery` anytime you wanted to work with jQuery.  This can get quite ugly:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('a', '#content').bind('click', function(){
        if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == 'www.google.com')
        {
            alert("This link goes to Google");
            jQuery(this).addClass('clicked'));
        }
    });
})
```

Remember, we can't use `$` because that is a method from Prototype in the global scope.

But if you wrapped it inside of this..

```
(function($){
    $(function(){

        // your code here

    });
})(jQuery);
```

The `$` would actually reference the jQuery library inside while still referring to Prototype on the outside!  This can help tidy up your code:

```
(function($){
    $(function{}(
        jQuery('a', '#content').bind('click', function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr('href') == 'www.google.com')
            {
                alert("This link goes to Google");
                jQuery(this).addClass('clicked'));
            }
        });
    ));
})(jQuery);
```

This is a common pattern with jQuery extensions to ensure that they are always added to the jQuery object, but can be written using `$` to keep the code tidy.

Comment: Are you aware of the $.noConflict() function? This removes the dependency on $. for instance var j = $.noConflict(); indicates that the variable j is now equal to $ thus j("#ElementId"); would be valid.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't want to use both together, is there something you're doing that requires you to?

In the jquery api documentation here, http://api.jquery.com/ready/, you can see these examples:

> The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
>
> });
>
> Which is equivalent to calling:
>
> $(function() {
>   // Handler for .ready() called.
>
> });

But I'm not sure if this answers your question because I don't see where you actually ask one.  Hope this helps just the same!

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you would introduce another closure is to introduce another scope boundary for loading / protecting global objects such as $.

For Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Do upper scope things.

    (function(){

        // Do lower scope things.

    })();

});
```

Based on you saying you have recently learning about this stuff I assume you are relativly new to JavaScript.

I have put together a blog post that might help explaining some of the basic concepts form the point of view of a newcomer to JavaScript, including function scope. http://bit.ly/tLkykX

Comment: Thanks for the link Maurice.  Good read.  I'd mark yours and Colin's correct if I could.